# Attempting to install XDebug in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am trying to install and run XDebug in Visual Studio Code. The modules are installed but when I select "run" and then "start debugging", and then select 'php xdebug' from the select box of available debuggers, I receive the following error message:

Cannot activate the 'PHP Xdebug' extension because it depends on an unknown 'felixfbecker.php-debug' extension.

Most of the tutorials on the subject mention that there is an extension that is necessary to be installed, "PHP Debug" by Felix Becker, but when I search for it in the "Extensions" sidebar on the left hand side, I cannot seem to find it (but I see several other extensions name 'PHP Debug' but attributed to different authors).

I wondered if anyone might be able to shed an insight as to where this Extension is and what its called?

Thanks,

Robert

Answer (score 1):

The "PHP Debug by Felix Becker" has been moved to https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug with the new name (not including felixbecker in either name or identifier). You do not need the "PHP Xdebug" extension, as I don't know what that is.

You might just have to uninstall all PHP and Xdebug related plugins, and reinstall the right one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xdebug.php-debug